How to configure HTTPS with a self-signed certificate in a .NET Core 8 app migrated from .NET Core 3
I'm trying to enable HTTPS in my .NET Core 8 application migrated from .NET Core 3 using a self-signed certificate for local development. I've generated the certificate using OpenSSL and added it to my project, but I'm encountering errors when trying to configure Kestrel to use it.
Below is what my Startup.cs looks like:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    
    app.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "password"); // Configuring HTTPS with the self-signed certificate
    
}

The above code directs me to the below error:

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the
default developer certificate could not be found.

I've followed the official documentation on Microsoft's website for configuring HTTPS in .NET Core, but I'm still stuck with no luck.

.NET 8 doesn't use Startup.cs or IApplicationBuilder and HTTPS is on by default, using the self-signed developer certificate created by dotnet dev-certs. Are you migrating a web app that started in ASP.NET Core 3.x? The ASP.NET Core 8 HTTPS docs have several sections on enabling the dev certificate on Windows, Mac, Linux, Docker, WSL

You need to specify a certificate explicitly in production. If you use IIS or NGINX, the certificate is configured there. Fro Kestrel the process is explained in the Endpoints Configuration documentation which shows how you can specify certificate files through settings or by calling UseHttps inside ConfigureWebServer to tell Kestrel which certificates to use

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes I am migrating from 3.XX to 8.. Any bottle necks likely to be found along the way?

A lot. There were far more changes from 3 to 6 than 6 to 8. Instead of trying to get the old project to run on .NET 8, try creating an ASP.NET Core 8 web app to see how things work now.
